# Javascript more/less text buttons for asp:label

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dynamically-generated

I am dynamically creating controls, one of which is a label control. If the label.Text.Length is greater than a certain character count I want More/Less Text buttons to appear to shorten/expand the text.  I got this function to work properly when using server side code, however, I want to do this with the client side code to prevent a postback from occuring.

So I figure that I would be dynamically adding javascript somehow? I'm not really sure what the javascript would look like though if this is possible.

```
LinkButton btn_more = new LinkButton();
btn_more.ID = "lblCustomControl" + (i + 1).ToString() + "_more";
btn_more.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.SlateBlue;
btn_more.Text = " [Show More]";
btn_more.Font.Underline = false;
btn_more.Click += new EventHandler(btn_more_Click);

LinkButton btn_less = new LinkButton();
btn_less.ID = "lblCustomControl" + (i + 1).ToString() + "_less";
btn_less.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.SlateBlue;
btn_less.Font.Underline = false;
btn_less.Text = " [Show Less]";
btn_less.Click += new EventHandler(btn_less_Click);
btn_less.Visible = false;
```

I am currently creating buttons like so and adding them into a table cell that contains the label. I'm guessing that I have to replace the btn_more/less.Click with

```
btn_more/less.OnClientClick = "my javascript stuff" + btn_less/more.ID + "more javascript stuff" + myLabel.ID;
```

obviously not in that order, but i'm guessing that is how I would dynamically add a javascript action to my button.

Any advice would by great! thanks (:

Answer (score 2):

You can bind javascript this way.

```
btn_more.Attributes.Add("onclick", "TestFun(this);");
```

In html side

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 function TestFun(obj)
 {          
      alert("I am test fun clicked by " + this.id);
      //for server side label
      document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('<%= LinkButton1.ClientID %>').style.display = "block"; 

      //For client side html element which do not have attribute runat="server"
      document.getElementById('Label1').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('myanchor').style.display = "block"; 
 }

</script>
```

Comment: yep. you might also have: `btn_more.Attributes.Add("onclick", "TestFun("+btn_more.ClientID+");");` to pass the id of the particular button that was clicked.

Comment: ah, even better! and mine should have been: btn_more.Attributes.Add("onclick", "TestFun('"+btn_more.ClientID+"');")

Comment: Thanks for this (: I'll try to use it. If you add a bit of code that changes a linkbutton and label's visibility i'll give you the checkmark

Comment: When I click on the button, this.id is returning "undefined", and if I try using btn_more.ClientID, I get a javascript error that says that the --insert button id-- is null.

Comment: Do you pass this as in this statement btn_more.Attributes.Add("onclick", "TestFun(this);"); and make sure you have assigned id to btn_more

Comment: Yeah, I passed the statement and set the ID. It's okay, I got around it by passing the ID as a string. I will try using your code and i'll let you know how it goes (:

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work :P I keep receiving this error:Timestamp: 27/06/2012 2:54:00 PM
Error: ctl00_phContents_UC_ViewBusinessEntity1_lblCustomControl10 is not defined
Source File: http://localhost:51115/BusinessEntity/ViewBusinessEntity.aspx?id=270
Line: 1